# How to find what has changed in a commit ID in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

How can the lastUpdated field for a merged-commit change?
I have a commit for which it was changed twice and how could I find out what was change during the update?
I mean I want to know if any file was modified or just a comment was added (I think in a merged commit, files can't be changed).

Answer (score 0):

To see what was changed you need to look at the "**History**" section of the change.

In history section, you can identify new patchsets events like the examples following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But pay attention in these important points:

- Files only can be changed if you have new patchsets added.
- New patchsets only can be added if the change is NOT merged yet.

So, in your case you're looking at "merged" changes so it's impossible to have any files changed.

Comment: I just updated my answer: 1. There's no way to know what have changed using the "gerrit query" command, 2. You're looking at "merged" changes so it's impossible to have file changes (new patchsets) in this situation.

Comment: I see. Is there any other solution? I know stream-event option but I dont understand how to implement it for Proof build.